Excel Labs Advanced Formula Environment works on other than english versions of Excel
I've installed the Excel Labs Advanced Formula Environment add-in in my Excel installation and it appears as expected. Bur I'm unable to get formulas to appear in the code editor window. That rises the question if the Excel Labs Advanced Formula Environment works on other than english versions of Excel where keywords is translated?

If you install the English language does the add-on work for you?

Tried but it seems that I'm not allowed to do that change. Need administrator rights to make Excel use english formulas. I do not have these rights due to company policies. Guess that means "end of the road" then. Thank you anyway.
